# converting file from .ods to xls file

Tags: file

I have a file in .ods format,

How to access that file in vb.net?,which connection string i have to use? and

how to convert that .ods file to .xls file? i used file.copy function,the extension of filename is changed to .xls,but the Save as type of filename won't change,any solution is there programatically.

which converter format,i have to use for converting .ods to .xls file?

Answer (score 1):

The only practical way of converting a .ods file into a .xls file is to open it in a spreadsheet program that supports reading ODF files and writing to Microsoft's (proprietary) Excel format.  All you have to do is open it and resave it in the desired format.  OpenOffice can kinda do this well, but any spreadsheets with more than a little complexity (contains graphs, functions other than the basic ones like SUM, etc) can be fouled up.  There is, however, a plug-in for MS Office for reading and writing ODF files, and it may even be built in now.  There are also drop through converters, but I have never used them.

Answer (score 1):

Very late but you can use this one:
http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support/articles/convert-xls-xlsx-ods-csv-html-net